# Cordova can't access http but can for https

Tags: php, ajax, cordova

I am developing a phoneapp using cordova app. I am using ajax request to access php file, and I am moving my webhost because I havbe troubles with it.
Before to access my php file it was 'https://...' but now it's 'http://...' 
And I don't know why but it's not working anymore, the php file is working on my laptop but not on the app. 
Here is my meta tag working for https :

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' https: data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *">
```

maybe I am missing something on it. I am getting a status code of 0 with the error method of ajax.

If someone has an answer.

thank you

Comment: Is it on the iOS platform that isn't working?

Answer (score 0):

Hi @lucas Can you remove your meta content for https and related things. Here I include my project meta tags details. It will working fine.

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src * 'self' gap: ; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'">
```

Comment: Could it be a question of cookie ? The webhost is sending me cookies but I can't treat them on android and that's why it's not working.
I have an error saying "This site requires javascript to work"

Comment: You can connect your mobile device into the system, then debugging in your mobile application. The Chrome browser console is shown the extract error, That error will put in stack overflow comments please.